# Use of 1W offset - Would like that offset by one week pushes current TS to begining of next week

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

## Initial problem statement

Given timestamp '2020-03-24 10:00' (a Tuesday), I would like to get next week start (Monday 00:00) by use of a week DateOffset.

I intend to understand the way DateOffset work.

Here are my attempts, all failing so far.

```
# ts being timestamp for Tuesday the 24th
ts = pd.Timestamp('2020-03-24 10:00')
# I am looking for the offset that will give me Monday the 30th 00:00

# Attempt 1 / by use of to_offset()
off1 = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('1W')
ts1 = ts + off1
# ts1 is set to next Sunday the 29th 00:00, why this specific date?
# Begining of week is Monday the 30th 00:00
ts1
>>> Out: Timestamp('2020-03-29 00:00:00')

# Attempt 2 / by use of DateOffset(weeks=1)
off2 = pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(weeks=1)
ts2 = ts + off2
# ts2 is now Tuesday the 31st 00:00
# It is not what I am looking for, but it makes sense.
# This offset is shifting current date to 7 days later, ok.
ts2
>>> Out: Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00')

# Attempt 3 / by use of DateOffset(weekday=1)
off3 = pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(weekday=1)
ts3 = ts + off3
# This time, I cannot figure any reason why the timestamp is
# simply not modified.
ts3
>>> Out: Timestamp('2020-03-24 10:00:00')
```

Please, has anyone any explanation for results ts1 & ts3.
What logic does follow the computation managed to obtain them?

And finally, has anyone any idea how to 'replace' Timestamp value to begining of next week? (I would have thought to onbtain this result with ts3, and hoping to have the same result with ts1, but it is currently a failure).

## Completed problem statement

First answer given below support use of an anchored DateOffset, which appears indeed anchoring the begining of next week to my expectation: anchoring it to Monday.

But now, looking for consistency, if I use this same anchored offset to create a PeriodIndex, weeks appear anchored to Tuesday?!

```
# ts being timestamp for Tuesday the 24th
ts = pd.Timestamp('2020-03-24 10:00')
ts_end=pd.Timestamp('2020-04-16 10:00')
# Offset
off1 = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('W-MON')
# PeriodIndex
pi = pd.period_range(start=ts_start, end=ts_end, freq=off1)
# Checking anchoring day of created PeriodIndex:
pi[1].start_time
>>> Out: Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00')
```

What mystery is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, consider this code:

```
# ts being timestamp for Tuesday the 24th
ts = pd.Timestamp('2020-03-24 10:00')
# use right offset to start with monday
off1 = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('W-MON')
# add values
ts1 = ts + off1
# call normalize to start at midnight
ts1 = ts1.normalize()
```

For ['W-MON'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) see 'Anchored offsets', for [normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) search page for 'use normalize()'.

---

**EDIT #1**

Answering your question about 'mystery' edit: use `pi[0].start_time` instead of `pi[1].start_time` to get the first element. Then you will get

```
pi[0].start_time
>>2020-03-24 00:00:00
```

However, I can't tell you why it does generated 03-**24** exactly, but it is very likely that the function finds the previous date corresponding to start of the week with `weekday` specified in the `frequency` and then uses one week (exactly 7 days) as frequency. It is (seemingly) baked by the fact, if one uses

```
off1 = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('1W-FRI') #weekday = 4
pi[0].start_time
>> 2020-03-21 00:00:00
pi[0].end_time
>> 2020-03-27 23:59:59.999999999
pi[1].start_time
>> 2020-03-28 00:00:00
pi[1].end_time
>> 2020-04-03 23:59:59.999999999
```

i.e. the ranges starts from Saturday. You can use calculated desired date as start (as shown above) and specify frequency as `'1W'` without anchors.

```
# ts being timestamp for Tuesday the 24th
ts = pd.Timestamp('2020-03-24 10:00')
# use right offset to start with monday
off1 = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('W-MON')
# add values
ts1 = ts + off1
# call normalize to start at midnight
ts1 = ts1.normalize()
#ts1 is 2020-03-30 00:00:00
ts_end=pd.Timestamp('2020-04-16 10:00')
# PeriodIndex
pi = pd.period_range(start=ts1, end=ts_end, freq= to_offset('1W'))

pi[0].start_time
>> 2020-03-30 00:00:00

pi[-1].start_time
>> 2020-04-13 00:00:00

pi[-1].end_time
>> 2020-04-19 23:59:59.999999999
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, I think you point in the direction I am looking for. I tried your solution and albeit it does work for summing Timestamp & DateOffset, it does not work for period_range(). I completed the problem statement with this *?inconsistency?*. Please, can you further comment it? What is I am doing the wrong way?
Thanks so much for your help and support!

Comment: Hi, Finally found out the why. The day that marks the anchor for a week is its last day. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1839
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

from Python 3.8+ the datetime module has a new class method `.fromisocalendar`

```
@classmethod
def fromisocalendar(cls, year, week, day):
    """Construct a date from the ISO year, week number and weekday.

    This is the inverse of the date.isocalendar() function"""
```

Given that you have a pandas datetime object,

```
from datetime import date
week = ts.week +1
year = ts.year 

new_date = date.fromisocalendar(year,week,1)
print(new_date)

2020-03-30
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for brining this. At the moment, I am delving with pandas time utils and would like to go on in this direction. Thanks again.